# Set NoProofing to True

Tags: vba, ms-word, spell-checking

I'm creating a macro for Word 2003.

I want to set NoProofing to True. It is still set to false after the macro executes.

If the cursor is on a new line, it works. However, if it is on an existing line, NoProofing is enabled for any new text (words) added to the document.

```vb
Sub Proofing()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wordCount As Integer
    wordCount = ActiveDocument.Words.Count
    
    For i = 1 To (wordCount - 1)
        ActiveDocument.Words(i).NoProofing = True
    Next i 
End Sub
```

(Note: this code will eventually be used to detect if the spell check has been completed, as Word discards the spell check once the document is saved and opened again, for XLSX format.)

Answer (score 0):

The spellcheck status is set as part of Word styles, so new text reverts to the value set in the style. By default, styles inherit the language settings from Normal style. Running this on a standard MS template will turn off spellchecking on all text:

```
Sub NoProofing()
    ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").NoProofing = True
End Sub
```

If you want this setting for all your future documents, open your Normal.dot template in Word, set Normal style to No Proofing and save the template. The macro will then be superfluous.